# any method to print invoice through android application?

Tags: android, invoice

Is there any way to print invoices with your android app when device attached with printer?? or any other method through which invoices can be print through app?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways i can think of doing this,

using android: much like described here [Printing from Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699640/printing-from-android)

by using an intent you can pass a file to another application of the users choice, they will see a dialog list which asks which application they would want to open (displaying list of printer applications installed).

alternatively you could set up a php script on a server to email a document you upload, or you could email directly from the device, if you have a printer with the ePrint service like described here: https://h30495.www3.hp.com/c/46502/US/en/?jumpid=in_R11549%2Feprintcenter

the second option is more complicated to set up but will enable you to print to your office from home or while commuting or anywhere with an internet access.